# Difficultly in changing gears

Tags: transmission, manual-transmission, gears

I have ford fiesta. Car was in good condition. All of a sudden, I started facing a weird issue which my mechanic also facing tough time identifying the real problem. My car is running fine from the first start in the morning. I am able to change the gears smoothly. After 15mins of driving gear shifting slowly gets tight and after half an hour, I have to put more pressure to change the gears. After I stop the car and let the car cool down, the gear shifting getting back to normal and this cycle repeats. I don't see any problems with the clutch as it is recently changed.

Gear oil is good. 
Clutch is engaging and disengaging fine.
No grinding noise observed while disengaging clutch and while shifting gears.

This is happening with all the gears. Did anyone face this kind of issue or anyone knows the fix?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! How many miles since the clutch change?

Comment: @Paulster2 It covered 500miles

Comment: After the hard shifting problem occurred, I made the car come to a complete stop. Kept in neutral and clutch is disengaged from the input. Engine didnt stall and there was not forward force. Even now, It was pretty difficult to put from N to 1st gear. So, I feel clutch is not the culprit here.

Comment: Well, that's exactly a situation which can be caused by the clutch not fully disengaging, so don't rule it out. The clutch can be free enough as to not transfer any torque from the engine to the wheels (a lot is needed to move the car) when in gear and stationary, but not free enough to allow the idling gears to move slightly so they can mesh from neutral (which doesn't take much force).

Comment: The reason I asked about the age of the clutch is if the clutch is tight and not broken in completely, it will *swell* some during operation (ie: engage/disengage cycle) due to heat. This can cause a little bit of drag on the clutch, which means it isn't fully disengaging. As soon as it cools down, no problem. This can be *very typical* of a new clutch, so would not discount it.

Comment: I second Weather Vane and Paulster. I have a truck which experienced almost the exact described issue. When I tightened the clutch adjustment bolt by the clutch pedal so it disengaged a tiny bit sooner, the problem went away.

Comment: In addition to the issue with the clutch being mis- adjusted (which I agree should be your #1 suspect since you recently had it serviced!) you may have a bent or improperly installed shift linkage, bent shift forks in the transmission, improperly filled transmission (i.e. wrong fluid), or another problem related to removal and re-installation of the transmission.

Comment: Also, I'll mention that the friction profile of the clutch will change as it's used. I installed a new clutch in my bike, and everything was fine for like 2500 miles, until suddenly I couldn't get it to disengage. Upon inspection, I had it wrongly adjusted (way over torqued) for the entire 2500 miles - but the issue didn't present itself. The point is that the clutch didnt "break in" for a while, so 500 miles would not be surprising at all.